# Released my first web application and I got a job offer to do contracting work. I dont know what to do

Tags: software-development, careers, freelancing, contracting

I am a system administrator by trade, but I want to move in to web development. I started learning on my spare time and I released my first personal project and have gotten positive feedback and an offer to do contracting work.

I have not enquired anything about what the job might be and I dont know what to do. I could see myself doing freelancing work, but I am not very confident with my skills yet. Should I just fake it till I make it? Or should I apply for a junior webdev position in a company? Any other advice to handle contracting offers?

Thanks.

Comment: congrats on moving in the direction you want! What do you want to do in life? Do you want to take this job, do you want to do freelancing as main occupation, do you want to work for MegaCorp? Do you want to work full-time for startup?

Answer (score 4):

Discuss with them, ask what they need, tell them what skills you have, at which level. In that way, you will have more information, and they will have more information, and the decision will be more fair for everybody.

Note that it is perfectly normal to have emotions about this. Just do not let the emotions overwhelm you, and they will slowly go away.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply to multiple other jobs at companies. Having only a single offer on the table is generally not a good way to make a career decision.

Additionally, you will almost certainly get much better experience and grow more as a developer on a team where you are working with more senior developers who can guide and mentor you. If that's not an option in this contracting role, that would make it much less attractive. That said, getting the contracting position might make it easier to land a better position in the future. You'll have a better idea if that's required by applying to other positions and seeing if they give you feedback that a: you're offered a position or b: you need more experience.

**Make sure the experience you get with this contracting position is worthwhile if you're going to consider it at all.**

Answer (score 0):

First the step in development is requirements gathering: What do they want?

Broadly, this process works as follows:

- Requirements Gathering - understand what the product they want is and how it's intended to be used.
- Begin design on the application (the problem domain, the tech you'll be using, the overall architecture)
- Start development by wiring up the first page and making sure you've connected all your tech together.
- Then using that single page as a prototype build out from there using the same structure.
- At some point once a few pages are built, meet back with your client to make sure the pages are following expectations and follow up on any changes.
- Build more and test and show the client.

After the initial set-up a lot of the process is requirements -> analysis -> production -> Feedback -> Back to requirements

[Further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development)... just a suggestion...

> I have not enquired anything about what the job might be and I dont know what to do.

Step One : [Requirements Gathering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_elicitation)